# Centering orthogonal lines over points and gridlines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got some data. Each point has a confidence interval width associated with it. I'd like to plot data points and then add the associated x/y confidence interval. I can do that with the code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cm as cm

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=10),
    'y': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=10),
    'x-int-width': np.random.rand(10)*1.2,
    'y-int-width': np.random.rand(10)*1.2,
})

df['x2'] = df['x-int-width'] / 2
df['y2'] = df['y-int-width'] / 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

ax.scatter(df.x, df.y)

colors = cm.viridis(df.index / (df.shape[0] - 1))

ax.hlines(y=df.y, xmin = (df.x - df.x2).values, xmax = (df.x + df.x2).values, colors=colors)
ax.vlines(x=df.x, ymin = (df.y - df.y2).values, ymax = (df.y + df.y2).values, colors=colors)

ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)
ax.grid()
ax.tick_params(which='both', width=0)
```

[image]

The problem is a super nit-picky, tiny detail. If you zoom in on the points, the lines don't exactly bisect the points. Look at the 4 points below. The top left pie of the circle is smaller than the others. If you look at the lines matching with the grid lines, you can see that the vertical line is slightly offset, to the left, of the vertical grid line. Same thing for the horizontal grid line.

[image]

How do I center the hlines and vlines over the gridlines (and therefore the points)?

Comment: Can you please post the complete code? The first figure is not exactly reproducible with the code you have shared.

Comment: this is the complete code. Copy and paste and try it out.